# how can I get specific supplier for each product in sale order line in odoo?

Tags: odoo-10, product

I try to put the supplier in new field so when I select product in sale order line his supplier automatic appear in new field by this function : but did not work

```py
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order.line'
_name = 'sale.order.line'

partner_name=fields.Char(compute='_count')

@api.depends()        
def _count(self):        
    count = self.env['res.partner'].search([('name', '=', self.ids)])
    self.partner_name = count
```

Comment: use related functionality@alyaa

Comment: I try it but also did not work

Comment: partner_name=fields.Char(related='product_id.supplier_ids.name')

Comment: Have you tried the onchange function?@alyaa

Comment: I am faced some problem in it

Comment: Show that problem please

Comment: there are three fields(name from res.partner,  supplier_ids from product.supplierinfo,  product_tmpl_id from product.template) I dont Know which I select

Comment: tell the question clearly pls, I think it is easy only

Comment: @api.onchange('partner_name')
    def _onchange_partner_name(self):
       
            self.partner_id.name.id = self.partner_name

Comment: finally it work!!..


    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def _onchange_partner_name(self):
        for partner in self.product_id:
            for x in partner.seller_ids:
                for y in x.name:
                    self.partner_name=y.name

Comment: I want to get specific partner for product

Comment: so is it working now?